# Here am getting error as operand expected,error token is +

Tags: arrays, shell

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo "enter an integer "
read $val

for((i=0;i<=2;i++))
do
Numbers[$i]=$val
done
echo ${Number[@]}
if [ $((${Number[0]}+${Number[1]}+${Number[2]})) -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Sum is Zero"
else
        echo "Sum is not zero"
fi
```

Comment: `Number` is not `Numbers`

Comment: @oguz, the `$((...))` is inside the `[..]`'s, so that should be arithmetic context, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Paul Oh yeah, my bad, I didn't pay attention

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo "enter an integer "
read val  # read takes the name of a variable

for((i=0;i<=2;i++))
do
Numbers[$i]=$val
done
echo ${Numbers[@]}  # from here on, you wrote "Number" instead of "Numbers"
if [ $((Numbers[0] + Numbers[1] + Numbers[2])) -eq 0 ]  # you don't need $ to read variables in arithmetic expansions
then
        echo "Sum is Zero"
else
        echo "Sum is not zero"
fi
```